# How can I build and return a large zip file in a performant manner?

Tags: c#, azure, stream, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

### Background

---

I'm currently working on a **.Net Core - C#** application that is reliant on various Azure services. I've been tasked with creating an endpoint that allows users to bulk download a varying number of files based on some querying/filtering. The endpoint will be triggered by a download all button on the frontend and should return a **.zip** of all said files. The total size of this zip could be anywhere from **100KB-100GB** depending on the query/filters provided.

**Note**: Although I'm familiar with Asynchrony, Concurrency, and Streams. Interactions between these and between api layers is something Im still getting my head around. Bear with me.

### Question

How can I achieve this in a performant and scalable manner given some architectural constraints? ***Details provided below.***

### Architecture

[image: High Level Azure Workflow]

The backend currently consist of 2 main layers. The **API Layer** consist of [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?tabs=in-process) which are the first point of contact for any and all request from the frontend. The **Service Layer** stands in-between the **API Layer** and other Azure Services. In this particular case the **Service Layer** interacts with an [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction) Container, where the various files are stored.

### Current Implementation/Plan

#### Request:

[image: Request Workflow Diagram]
The request itself is strait forward. The **API Layer** takes query's and filters and turns that into a list of filenames. That is then sent in the body of a POST request to the **Service Layer**. The **Service Layer** loops through the list and retrieves each file individually from the blob storage. As of right now there is no way of bulk downloading attachments. This is where complications start.

- Given the potential file size, can't pull all data into memory at one time, may need to be streamed or batched.
- Given many files, may need to download files in parallel from blob storage.
- Need to build zip file from async parallel task? Which can't be built completely in memory.

#### Response:

[image: Response Workflow Diagram]
I currently have a working version of this that doesn't worry about memory. The above diagram is meant as an illustration of the limitations/considerations of the task rather than a concept that can be put to code. No one layer can/should hold all of the data at any given time. My original attempt/idea was to use a series of streams that can pipe data down the line in some manor. However, I realized this might be a fools errand and decided to make this post.

Any thoughts on a better high-level work flow to accomplish this task would be greatly appreciated. I would also love to hear completely different solutions to the problem.

Comment: Please see this article https://josef.codes/azure-storage-zip-multiple-files-using-azure-functions/

Comment: Why did you reject using streams? Conceptually that seem to be the most flexible way to transfer data from different places.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Sha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560784/sha). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

1. POST a list of file paths to a Azure Function (Http trigger)
2. Create a queue message containing the file paths and put on a storage queue.
3. Listen to said storage queue with another Azure function (Queue trigger).
4. Stream each file from Azure Storage -> Add it to a Zip stream -> Stream it back to Azure storage.

Below code will help on creating ZIP file.

```cs
public class AzureBlobStorageCreateZipFileCommand : ICreateZipFileCommand
{
    private readonly UploadProgressHandler _uploadProgressHandler;
    private readonly ILogger<AzureBlobStorageCreateZipFileCommand> _logger;
    private readonly string _storageConnectionString;
    private readonly string _zipStorageConnectionString;
        
    public AzureBlobStorageCreateZipFileCommand(
        IConfiguration configuration,
        UploadProgressHandler uploadProgressHandler,
        ILogger<AzureBlobStorageCreateZipFileCommand> logger)
    {
        _uploadProgressHandler = uploadProgressHandler ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uploadProgressHandler));
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _storageConnectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("FilesStorageConnectionString") ?? throw new Exception("FilesStorageConnectionString was null");
        _zipStorageConnectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("ZipStorageConnectionString") ?? throw new Exception("ZipStorageConnectionString was null");
    }
        
    public async Task Execute(
        string containerName,
        IReadOnlyCollection<string> filePaths,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var zipFileName = $"{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.{Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4)}.zip";
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        try
        {
            using (var zipFileStream = await OpenZipFileStream(zipFileName, cancellationToken))
            {
                using (var zipFileOutputStream = CreateZipOutputStream(zipFileStream))
                {
                    var level = 0;
                    _logger.LogInformation("Using Level {Level} compression", level);
                    zipFileOutputStream.SetLevel(level);
                    foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
                    {
                        var blockBlobClient = new BlockBlobClient(_storageConnectionString, containerName, filePath);
                        var properties = await blockBlobClient.GetPropertiesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                        var zipEntry = new ZipEntry(blockBlobClient.Name)
                        {
                            Size = properties.Value.ContentLength
                        };
                        zipFileOutputStream.PutNextEntry(zipEntry);
                        await blockBlobClient.DownloadToAsync(zipFileOutputStream, cancellationToken);
                        zipFileOutputStream.CloseEntry();
                    }
                }
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();
            _logger.LogInformation("[{ZipFileName}] DONE, took {ElapsedTime}",
                zipFileName,
                stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            var blockBlobClient = new BlockBlobClient(_zipStorageConnectionString, "zips", zipFileName);
            await blockBlobClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
            throw;
        }
    }

    private async Task<Stream> OpenZipFileStream(
        string zipFilename,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var zipBlobClient = new BlockBlobClient(_zipStorageConnectionString, "zips", zipFilename);
            
        return await zipBlobClient.OpenWriteAsync(true, options: new BlockBlobOpenWriteOptions
        {
            ProgressHandler = _uploadProgressHandler,
            HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders
            {
                ContentType = "application/zip"
            }
        }, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }

    private static ZipOutputStream CreateZipOutputStream(Stream zipFileStream)
    {
        return new ZipOutputStream(zipFileStream)
        {
            IsStreamOwner = false
        };
    }
}
```

Check [Zip File using Azure functions](https://josef.codes/azure-storage-zip-multiple-files-using-azure-functions/) for further information.